# Adding tabs with jQuery UI, then filling them with content via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, jquery-ui-tabs

Ok, so basically I'm using ui.tabs and I want to have a link in the first tab trigger the adding of 2 new tabs, both of which will be populated by an ajax call which is dependent on the value of the link clicked. I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="a">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <input class="imageID" type="hidden" value="11">
        <a href="#addTab" class="tabButton">asdfasdfasdfasfasf</a>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <input class="imageID" type="hidden" value="1">
        <a href="#addTab" class="tabButton">asdfasdfasdfasfasf</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then the jQuery so far looks like this:

```
$(function(){
    var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
    $('.tabButton').click(function(){
        tabs.tabs('add','test.htm','Summary');
        tabs.tabs('add','test.htm','Read Topic');
    });

    $(".tabButton").live("click", function(){
        var getImageID = $(this).parent();
        $.get("ajax.php?c=" + $(".imageID",getImageID).val(), function() {

        });
    });
});
```

Now the jQuery works so far, it's picking up the value of the hidden input field properly and returning the correct response from ajax.php (visible in Firebug's console), but what I have no idea how to achieve is how to have the tabs added with the correct information. Basically, ajax.php queries a database and pulls out the content of 2 fields (obviously the record varies depending on the value sent). The content of the first field would then be displayed in the new 'Summary' tab, and the content of the second field would be placed in the second new tab, 'Read Topic'. However, I have no idea how to structure the jQuery to achieve this (I'm fairly new to the subject).

(Obviously I'm aware that lines 3-6 of the jQuery won't be needed once this is coded correctly).

Comment: did you find the solution to your question in the end?

Comment: sorry John, i've been at work all day, going to have a play with it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've used elements of the other answers, and ended up with this working code:

```
$(function(){   
    var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
    $(".tabButton").live("click", function(){
        var getImageID = $('.imageID',$(this).parent()).val();
            tabs.tabs('add', 'ajax.php?content=summary&id=' + getImageID, 'Summary');
            tabs.tabs('add', 'ajax.php?content=read&id=' + getImageID, 'Read Topic');
    });
});
```

with the link that causes it to fire being the same as in my original question. I think the reason I've done it differently is because I've fired it off a button click. Does this seem a correct and reasonable use of jquery?

Comment: The basic idea behind this is an archive list of documents in chronological order, the first tab containing the list of links which then fires off the creation of the summary and read tabs. 

Now if the person decides to read a second document, they're going to end up with several open tabs, which isn't the best example of a good UI. Is there anyway I can force the newly-created tabs to have a specific class, and have the click event look for tabs with that class and remove them before it creates the new ones?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are actually pretty close to what you want. Something like this?

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input class="imageID" type="hidden" value="11">
            <a href="#addTab" class="tabButton">asdfasdfasdfasfasf</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function (event, ui) {
        if (!$(ui.tab).hasClass('tabButton')) {
            return; // exit because you did not select the first tab
        }

        var panel = $(ui.panel), summaryID, readID;
        summaryID = panel.find('#hidSummaryID').val();
        readID = panel.find('#hidReadID').val();
        tabs.tabs('add', 'summary.php?c=' + summaryID, 'Summary');
        tabs.tabs('add', 'read.php?c=' + readID, 'Read Topic');
    }
});
```

Where 'hidSummaryID' and 'hidReadID' store some value you need to get the correct info from the database.

Comment: I feel this is the answer I need, but as Javascript is something I just cannot seem to get my head around what the code is actually doing so I can implement it myself. My main sticking point is actually understanding what the panel variable acts on? Where would it look for hidSummaryID etc? In the tab containing the link which fires off the ajax request? Apologies if these questions are very basic.

Comment: Nah, it's good -- we were all learning this stuff at some point.  The panel variable acts on the div that gets loaded as a tab. So that would be what you view.  Inside that view you could have hidden fields that you use when you post to summary and read.  I would think that you would store those fields in the panel since the panel does not get loaded until you click it?

Comment: Ah, I see now where you are going with that code. Maybe a little pseudo code would help explain what i'm trying to achieve? I can see elements of what i need to do in your code.

`get id of hidden input when link in first tab is clicked` >
`store id of hidden input as a variable` >
`add tab 'summary' with ajax.php?content=summary&id=(hidden input value)` >
`add tab 'read' with ajax.php?content=read&id=(hidden input value)`

sorry for my rubbish comment formatting, but i'm not used to stackoverflow's commenting tags

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I was under the impression that there wouldn't be anything loaded until you clicked the first tab.  When the first tab was clicked, it loads a panel with hidden ids used in your summary and read calls.  This is the point that my code comes in.  The only thing I am not sure with in my answer is if the select event will fire after the ajax has loaded the tab's panel.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I can see this is your problem: "what I have no idea how to achieve is how to have the tabs added with the correct information."

```
$.get("ajax.php", { name: $(getImageID).val()}, function(data) { 
//get the json array in data var     
     $(this).after("<span class='title'>Title"+obj["title"]+"</span><span class='summary'>"+obj["text"]+"</span>"); //append a couple of spans with the data after you retrieve the unique data

});
```

Firstly your ajax.php page needs to be returning a simple JSON_encode'ed array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php, see this for more details.

The next step is when you are appending the new content AFTER the button you pressed, use .after to the documet view: http://api.jquery.com/after/

Here is a quick jFiddle that shows what the JSON encoded array is doing: http://jsfiddle.net/DKuK9/1/ 
it is applying a couple of spans with the arrayed content into the div, not precisly what your script is doing however i do not have a ajax page to call to :)

edit your get function usage was wrong-